# Extract a mixin from a common function in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, mixins

Consider two classes that each have an existing shared function, but separate inheritance paths:

```
class ClazzA(SuperClazzX):
    def foo(self):
        return goo(super(SuperClazzX, self).foo())

class ClazzB(SuperClazzY):
    def foo(self):
        return goo(super(SuperClazzY, self).foo())
```

`foo` is clearly a common function which can be extracted to a mixin, what is the right way to do so, such that the functionality remains even though a different super `foo` is to be called?

Edit: I removed the other mixin, it was confusing and irrelevant.

Comment: Are there other classes inheriting `CommonMixin`, could it go in there?

Comment: No, `CommonMixin` is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you talking about refactoring existing code or designing from scratch?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid This is existing code, but does it really matter?

Comment: I think so; maybe foo does different things in different classes? Looking it now, I think a decorator might be a better approach.

Comment: @YuvalAdam you ask if a method can be extracted to a mix-in; how is an existing mix-in shared by the classes irrelevant?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because it's not my code, it's an external dependency.

Comment: btw., you still use `super` wrong, it should be `... super(ClazzA, self).foo() ...` in ClazzA.

Comment: @qarma you are right, if you formulate that into a proper answer I can upvote and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: simpler code

Mixin has access to other bases of (future) child class, here `C::Mixin::foo` has access to the other base of `C`, namely `C::Base::foo`. [Authoritative explanation here](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

```
class Base(object):  # must be new-style class in py 2.x
    def foo(self):
        print "base foo called"

class Mixin(object):
    def foo(self):
        rv = super(Mixin, self).foo()  # call actual implementation
        # use rv

class C(Mixin, Base):
    pass

C().foo()
base foo called
```

What this does:

- `self` is instance of `C`, it's `__mro__` is (Mixin, Base)
- when Mixin calls `super(Mixin, self)`, the resulting object retains bases (Base,)
- when `.foo` attribute is resolved, this object finds it in Base
- thus `Base.foo` is invoked with original `self`

If you want custom control over implementation, you have access to your own bases, e.g.:

```
class Foo(...):
    def foo(self):
        print self.__class__.__bases__
```

Your mixin could look something like this, super-manual approach:

```
class Mixin(object):
    def foo(self):
        assert self.__class__ is not Mixin  # no point calling directly
        # find the other base
        other = [b for b in self.__class__.__bases__ if b is not Mixin]
        # what to do if there's more than 1 real base?
        # pick base explicitly
        base = other[1]
        # call it, 
        return something(base.foo(self, some_args))
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @qarma hope it clarified :)

Comment: This seems wrong. Shouldn't Python be able to resolve the `super()` call properly with explicitly calling `self.__class__.__bases__`?

Comment: See, `super` doesn't return a reference to another base directly. It returns a magic object, that when you try to find `.foo` attribute in, will locate next class in chain that actually defines `.foo`.